# Keras LSTM layers in Keras-rl

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, keras-rl

I am trying to implement a DQN agent using Keras-rl. The problem is that when I define my model I need to use an LSTM layer in the architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, 8000)))
model.add(Reshape(target_shape=(200, 40)))
model.add(LSTM(20))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
return model
```

Executing the rl-agent I obtain the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

Which is related to the use of the LSTM and to the following line of code:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Using a Dense layer instead of an LSTM:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, 8000)))
model.add(Dense(20))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
return model
```

and maintaining eager execution disabled I don't have the previously reported error. If I delete the disabling of the eager execution with the LSTM layer I have other errors.

Can anyone help me to understand the reason of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keras-rl` library does not have explicit support for TensorFlow 2.0, so it will not work with such version of TensorFlow. The library is sparsely updated and the last release is around 2 years old (from 2018), so if you want to use it you should use TensorFlow 1.x

Answer (score 1):

Install keras-rl2 from github support tensorflow 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to migrate the code for keras-rl to use eager execution and therefore an LSTM. LSTMs need to be updated with a whole episode of learning to prove accurate something which keras-rl does not support. See more here: https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/issues/41